# What is a "vocal coach?"

Tags: practice, voice

What is a "vocal coach" and how does it differ or is specific in comparison to the vocal learning / training in general?

Answer (score 2):

A vocal coach helps you learn techniques to strengthen voice and breath, and extend range etc. They also identify bad habits and help you fix them.

They do carry out the tasks you describe as vocal learning.

Comment: Is this another term for 'singing teacher' ?

Comment: @Tim - I would actually say "no."  As someone suggested in another question, the term "teacher" implies a long-term relationship while "coach" implies a short term relationship. A vocalist may go to a voice teacher weekly, but may work with a vocal coach during an opera production for example.  I cannot see the reverse as being socially normal.

Comment: Maybe the term 'coach' has different connotations in different places. I've been a barefoot waterski coach for many years, and whilst I may have had students for long periods or for just a few sessions, I never call myself a 'teacher', only a coach. Interesting.Should add, this is in little old England.